# Shift File Cursor Two Lines In C

Tags: c, file, cursor, shift

i want to shift the cursor two lines. What i mean is i want to ignore first two lines and get the third line of a file. Here is my code:

```
void dosyaImlecOtele(int satir,FILE *dosya){
    int i,karakter;
    char temp[100];
    for(i=0;i<satir;i++){
        karakter = getc(dosya);
        while(karakter != '\n' && !feof(dosya)){
             karakter = getc(dosya);
        }
    }
    fread(temp,sizeof(char),100,dosya);
    printf("%s",temp);
    }
```

Where am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is the problem you're experiencing? Have you tried using a debugger? If you haven't, why?

Comment: yes i debugged it. It normally should jump the 3rd line, but when i execute and debug it doesn't read from the 3rd line.

Comment: Can you post a complete program, and describe the faulty output? You're not terminating temp, and you're not checking the error code from fread, but it's not clear that either of those mistakes are what you're seeing.

Comment: That's not much of analysis. What does it read?

Comment: what is the `satir` value?

Comment: i cannot post all the program because where i have problem is this function. I open a file and send it successfully to this function and in this function my ide,xcode, says bad_access_code at the line karakter = getc(dosya);

Comment: @Alex satir means how many lines i shift.

Comment: I asked the value, not meaning.

Comment: @user1972138 Never mind. I just wanted to clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

When the `for` loop ends, `karakter` contains the first character of the third line (presuming `satir` is 2), because it was read to discover it was not a new-line. You can put the character back into the stream with `ungetc`.